# Swagger YML: Can't execute file upload api. Box greys out and it doesn't allow me to move forward to see any type of response

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

This is first time learning swagger. What am I doing wrong here? Notice the chose file option in red on the right.

I am able to select any file, but as soon as I click execute it doesn't go past the this stage.

[image]

Comment: Do you have this api online? can you share a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5997) in Swagger UI 3.25.2. Fixed in v. 3.25.3.